# How to fetch data out of AsyncTask class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I want to know how to access the data and bind it to a component in out of the  AsyncTask  class body?

I have a class like:

```
class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {....}
```

and it has a method :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return ....;//return some data
    }
```

I don't understand doInBackground return data to where?

Because when i want to use my class, i use it like:

```
      DownloadData dd = new DownloadData();
            dd.execute(...);
```

can i use it like this? because i want to fetch returned data out of my main class to bind it to some components

```
      DownloadData dd = new DownloadData();
        string temp=dd.doInBackground(...);
```

Comment: look at answers and approve if it was helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `doInBackground()` your `return` will be forwarded to `onPostExecute()`.

To use it in your activity refer this link : [How to use Async result in UIThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I can not catch

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return ....;//return some data
    }
```

result from main UI.

You have to use callbacks. For example, you can use interface to obtain the result.

For example create an interface:

```
public interface IProgress {
    public void onResult(int result);
}
```

create class:

```
     private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private IProgress cb;
    DownloadData(IProgress progress)  {
    this.cb = cb;
    }
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
if (cb!=nil)
cb.onResult(i);//calls 10 times
}
....
    }
...
    }
```

somewhere in code:

```
DownloadData dd = new DownloadData( new IProgress() {
public void onResult(int result) {
/// this is your callback

//to update mainUI thread use this:
final res = result;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //update UI here
textview.setText("" + res);
                }
            });

}
});
            dd.execute(...);
```

And, as usual, you can update UI after `doInBackground` via `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return a result from your AsyncTask class so that you can update the UI in your activity according to the result you can do something like this:
In your AsyncTask class declare an interface like this:

```
private AsyncResponse asyncResponse = null;

public DownloadData(AsyncResponse as) {
    this.asyncResponse = as;
 }

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void onAsyncResponse(String result); // might be any argument length of any type
}
```

and in `onPostExecute()` :

```
asyncResponse.onAsyncResponse(result); // result calculated from doInBackground()
```

and in the activity class:

```
DownloadData dd = new DownloadData(new AsyncResponse() {...}); // implement onAsyncResponse here
dd.execute();
```